# How do I make *ngIf still be dynamic once the view has been rendered?

Tags: javascript, angular, event-handling

I hope the question makes sense, I am very new to Angular.

Essentially what I have is a *ngIf directive that changes color of a css property so that the user is warned when an Event is scheduled to start (but hasn't.).

```
<input type="hidden" *ngIf="isEventOverdue(event.startDatetime, event.status, i) == true" />



public isEventOverdue(eventStartTime:string, eventStatus:string, eventIndex:number):  boolean
{
    if (Event Status = 'Scheduled' && elapsed time since event start time >= 5mins) {
            this.events[eventIndex].view.statusColor = "red";

    }
}
```

Problem I'm facing is that, this function is fired only once and so that means the CSS property only changes on page refresh or load. How do I make the css property change instantaneously ?

Comment: `ngClass` is a better option in this case where you can set the condition dynamically to true or false and add/remove the css class . Else you can use a boolean flag which you can update from typescript and use that flag in ngIf

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestion, but how do I make this function execute every n seconds to constantly check the time elapsed ?

Comment: Create an Observable from interval and subscribe to it. It will emit a value as per given duration , you can measure the time from that.

Comment: Check this http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeinterval.html you can sum up the total time taken

Comment: Yes I see but how do I make the function be called with the parameters I need (which I get from the template) ? For brevity I left out the `ngFor` directive because all events are shown inside a table. And each row is an `event`. So I'm able to get `event.startDatetime`, `event.status`, `i` (Index)

Comment: `isEventOverdue` has no return value, so the *ngIf will always evaluate to same value (although, you may have omitted this in this version, but just to check :) ).

Comment: @miselking yes I omitted that for brevity. It returns true/false in addition to the css prop change.